# Windows XP: remote monitoring of CPU load

Tags: windows-xp, performance-monitoring

I have a Windows XP PC that I'm using as a server for a couple of apps. Is there a program I can use to monitor the memory usage / CPU load? The PC has Apache and PHP available.

(I don't need fast realtime updates, once every 5 seconds would be fine, I just want to see memory usage + CPU load and make sure my server's not overtaxed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perfmon (Performance Monitor) allows you to connect to a remote system if you have administrator credentials.

Comment: hmm, how do I do this? I run perfmon and it doesn't seem to have any options to do so.

Comment: On XP - When you add a Performance counter (the + icon) you can choose to enter a remote machine name and Perfmon will fetch the counters from that and present you with the list to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unix machine available somewhere you can set it up to poll the load of the windows machine (and a bunch of other statistics) using [Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/). You would set up a master collector on a unix machine and a node on the Windows machine (and any other computer you are interested in) using the windows node [installer](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/wiki/HowToMonitorWindows).